# Creating dropdownlist with relations in yii

Tags: php, yii, entity-relationship, html-select

I am a newbie in Yii framework and now I try to create dropdownlist from related table.
I have table "News"[...a lot of fields,category] and "NewsCategories"[id,category_name].
In form for creating new record in News I want to create a dropdownlist in category field when user can choose a category_name, but id of category have to be recorder in a new record.

Help me please with it. Sorry for my English. I hope what I explain it understandable.

Here is how I created relations

Model News.php

```
public function relations()
{

    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
    'category'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'NewsCategories', 'category'),
    );
}
```

Model NewsCategories.php

```
    public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
    'news'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'News', 'id'),
    );
}
```

And how I try to create dropdownlist:

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'category',CHtml::listdata(News::model()->with('category')->findAll(),'id','category_name'),array('empty'=>'(Select a category')));?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When specifying relations, you don't need to specify primary key (*id*), because yii can deduct primary key from the model. You only need to specify the other end, so your NewsCategory relation should look like this:

```
'news'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'News', 'category'),
```

To get data suitable for drop-down list, use

```
CHtml::listData(NewsCategories::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'category_name');
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I spend 2 days by trying solve this problem. Sorry but I cant vote for you because have not enought reputation.